# Network storage on SD-Card

Tags: file-server, data-transfer

I've set up a file server on my raspberry pi using a USB HDD for storage and the read and write speeds are very slow (2-3 MB/s)

My question is, if i create a partition on the SD-Card (16gb) and use that as storage instead, will that speed up the network transfer speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2-3MB/s is kind of slow, but it's very unlikely the HDD is the problem.

to check the disk interface speed, you may use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/yourHDD/somefile bs=10M count=100` and see the resulting write speed. on my raspi i've got:

```
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 50.0709 s, 20.9 MB/s
```

I don't think any SD card can beat this, also SD cards are prone to corruption, therefore I'd advise against using them for storage of any files you don't want to lose eventually.

for raspi-based HDD file storage you should expect speeds about 7-8MB/s with the correct network setup, and the main speed limiter is the speed of 100M ethernet.

Comment: When i write files or copy files from it the CPU-Usage spikes to 100%... Is that a limiting factor and is that normal?

Comment: if you have a relatively fresh HDD, the limiting factor should be USB2 speed, something around 20-25MB/sec. btw, what speed did you get from `dd` command?

Comment: I'm at work right now sorry. I'll be able to do it in an hour or two and I'll get back to you.

The HDD is not more than 6 months old and has never shown signs of it beginning to die. If i plug it in to my PC and just transfer to to the HDD in my pc, the speed is much greater. So that means the cause of the problem is in the network or the Pi.

Comment: i got kind of a strange result...
155623424 bytes (156 MB) copied, 460.156 s, 338 kB/s

the transfer speed is lower than over the network

Comment: Tried it again and this time i got "1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 302.117 s, 3.5 MB/s" the funny thing is, the file was only 3MB yet it says 1GB. the file has now been corrupted and somehow is 1GB now.

Answer (score 1):

The network and usb interfaces are connected so if you're copy data off your usb hdd across the network (or vice versa) you will potentially notice some speed degradation.

So yes, you can expect some speed improvements using the SD card over your USB HDD, but it does depend on your network set up. For example, with my wired network I never get better than 7MBps even though with my 100Mb line I theoretically could get up to 12.5MBps.